# Windows 10 randomly shutdown and cleared system logs at startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, event-viewer

I have a windows 10 desktop that shutdown unexpectedly. I didn't see it happen but it randomly went offline. When I booted it back up and the first event, per the event logs, was a "log clear". The details of the event are below. It was performed by user: S-1-5-18, which I believe is the system user? I don't see it listed anywhere else, but there are some records in the group policy editor that reference similar users: S-1-5-83, and S-1-5-21.

Following the clearing of the system log there were 6 more log clear events. 5 related to VisualSVN server, and 1 for the RemoteDesktopSessionManager/Admin log file.

I recently performed a system recovery operation on this desktop to clone the OS to a new hard drive, so not sure if those users are related to that? Either way, clearing the system logs seems suspicious, and prevents me from figuring out why the computer randomly shut down. I checked the windows update history and the restart doesn't correlate with any update operation.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Eventlog" Guid="{fc65ddd8-d6ef-4962-83d5-6e5cfe9ce148}" /> 
  <EventID>104</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>104</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-02-22T02:46:19.2450542Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>123051</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1456" ThreadID="11800" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>**********</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
<UserData>
<LogFileCleared xmlns="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/eventlog">
  <SubjectUserName>SYSTEM</SubjectUserName> 
  <SubjectDomainName>NT AUTHORITY</SubjectDomainName> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <BackupPath /> 
  </LogFileCleared>
  </UserData>
  </Event>
```

Are those user accounts and/or the log entry suspicious?

Comment: This is abnormal. Try to [Enable the Shutdown Event Tracker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/application-management/description-shutdown-event-tracker) to find why is Windows shutting down. Also to see if you have a shutdown script, run `gpedit.msc` and navigate to *Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)*.

Comment: @harrymc I enabled that setting, but I'm not sure it will have any effect if this is caused by some malicious process.
Also checked the GP Editor and there are no shutdown scripts.

Comment: You could do deep scans using Windows Defender and [Malwarebytes Free](https://www.malwarebytes.com/premium). You could also use [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to check all Scheduled Tasks, if one looks suspicious right-click it and select "Jump to Entry" to display in the Task Scheduler.

Comment: Is there a \windows\memory.dmp or a file under \windows\minidump that coincides?

Comment: @HelpingHand No, there is no memory.dmp file. The minidump folder is present, but it is empty.